# How to get related data from 2nd table in same select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
'people'
    id   |  name    | which_image
  --------------------------------
     1   |  Joey    |  1
     2   |  Bobby   |  2
     3   |  Jimmy   |  3

'images'
    id      |  filename
  --------------------------------
     1      |  joe_face.jpg
     2      |  bob_angry.jpg
     3      |  jim_laughs.jpg
```

How can I do one select to get all columns in the 'people' table for a couple of people, and in the same query, get their filenames? I've tried this but it returns an empty set:

```
SELECT p.*, i.filename FROM people p, images i
 WHERE ( p.id = 1 OR p.id = 3 ) 
   AND p.which_image = i.id
```

Comment: Your query is correct i think the problem in P.*....    try tension the column name like p.id , p.name ..

Comment: This query is complete correct.

Comment: What Mysql version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no real foreign key in 'images', use a sub-select as follows:

```
SELECT p.*, (select filename from images i where i.id=p.which_image) as filename  
FROM people p 
WHERE p.id in (1,3)
```

Comment: I think all these answers will work but I like yours the best; it's the most simple and clear to someone like me who still finds joins a bit of a mystery :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eric. You are correct. All three will work. I encourage you to learn about relationships - the database kind that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*,
       i.filename
FROM   people p
       INNER JOIN images i
         ON p.which_image = i.id
WHERE  p.id = 1
        OR p.id = 3;
```